# How can I mock caatchAsync(error handler) with jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, jestjs

Im trying to unit test some middleware.

```ss
export const someMiddleware = catchAsync(async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
//...
}
```

But  it always returns `undefined` because of `catchAsync`

```js
export const catchAsync = (fn: any) => {
  return function (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    fn(req, res, next).catch(next);
  };
};
```

```js
describe('some middleware test', () => {
  let mockRequest: Partial<Request>;
  let mockResponse: Partial<Response>;
  let nextFunction: NextFunction = jest.fn();

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockRequest = {};
    mockResponse = {
      json: jest.fn(),
    };
  });

  test('this some throw error', async () => {
    const result = await someMiddleware(mockRequest as Request, mockResponse as Response, nextFunction);
    expect(result).toEqual('...');
  });
});
```

So, what I'm missing or a keyword to resolve `catchAsync`?

Comment: Why would you test the return value of middleware? They don't return anything, they either respond to the request (using methods on the `res` argument) or call `next` to delegate to the next thing in the chain. I'm generally skeptical of unit-testing this kind of component - as you can see, it means you have to mock something you don't own, creating parts of the Express API. I'd recommend integration-level testing instead.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for your reply. I wanted to test throw errors in middleware if there were no 'user' in the 'req' object. I'll refer to the integration-level test

Comment: Think about what happens if that error gets thrown - it ends up in the `.catch` callback where it's passed to `next`, which is what's supposed to happen (so it ends up with any error-handling middleware in the chain). If you _do_ want to test that at a unit level, that's the behaviour you should be asserting on (and then it doesn't really matter whether it's done by `catchAsync` or just within `someMiddleware` itself, which tells you you're testing behaviour not implementation).